# Cypress - Build a mochawesome report from a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, cypress, mochawesome

for test purpose, I want to have a mochawesome report generated with a jenkins job :

I have a jenkins in local with Dockerfile.jenkins:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libgbm-dev \
    libnotify-dev \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    libasound2 \
    libxtst6 \
    xauth \
    xvfb \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER jenkins
```

then I added in my docker-compose.yml :

```
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" 
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
```

In jenkins, I configured the job as :

[image]
[image]

notes : the job is ok if I don't add the mochawesome report

But I get this error :

```
+ npx cypress run --reporter mochawesome
[281:0311/120434.279278:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: unknown error type: 

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:45311/devtools/browser/*******************
Error loading the reporter: mochawesome

We searched for the reporter in these paths:

 - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Cypress Test/mochawesome
 - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Cypress Test/node_modules/mochawesome

Learn more at https://on.cypress.io/reporters

Error: Cannot find module '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Cypress Test/node_modules/mochawesome'
Require stack:
- /var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/13.3.2/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/reporter.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1082:15)
    at n._resolveFilename (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:117603)
    at PackherdModuleLoader._tryResolveFilename (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:745720)
    at PackherdModuleLoader._resolvePaths (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:742510)
    at PackherdModuleLoader.tryLoad (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:740553)
    at Function.<anonymous> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:751373)
    at d._load (<embedded>:4474:29351)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at S.loadReporter (<embedded>:4479:19555)
    at S.initializeReporter (<embedded>:4526:26644)
    at S.startWebsockets (<embedded>:4526:26948)
    at S.open (<embedded>:4526:25245)
    at async v.create (<embedded>:4526:38921)
    at async O (<embedded>:4526:125935)
    at async W (<embedded>:4526:138758)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Cypress Test/cypress/report/mochawesome-report to /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Cypress Test/htmlreports/HTML_20Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Cypress Test/cypress/report/mochawesome-report' does not exist.
Finished: FAILURE
```